# What is the cause of the odd behaviour of the bitwise operator in the following code?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I have a method in my C# application which is attempting to pack an integer, but the shift operator is behaving strangely.
The comments in the code below show the contents of code as seen by the debugger after the execution of the line.

```
        long code = 0;          //0x0000000000000000
        code += (0x1111 << 32); //0x0000000000001111
        code += (0x2222 << 16); //0x0000000022221111
        code += (0x3333);       //0x0000000022224444
```

Take the first line, I would expect that the code contained in parentheses would be executed first, which would result in 0x1111 being shifted left by 32 bits, yet it isn't, but on the next line the shift does take place, and in the correct place as well (i.e. 0x2222 must be shifted before the add otherwise the result would be 0x33330000).

**What have I missed about the operator that explains this?**

Comment: The variable `code` is a long value, why do you assume 0x1111 is a long?

Comment: `0x1111` *was* shifted left by 32. It just so happens that that's equivalent to shifting left by 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you missed is that bit shift operations on ints are mod 32. Since `0x1111` is an `int`, the operation is `0x1111 << (32 % 32)`, which is `0x1111 << 0`, which is just `0x1111`.

**What you probably want is `0x1111L << 32`.**

From section 7.9 of the C# spec:

> - When the type of x is `int` or `uint`, the shift count is given by the low-order five bits of `count`. In other words, the shift count is computed from `count & 0x1F`.
> - When the type of x is `long` or `ulong`, the shift count is given by the low-order six bits of `count`. In other words, the shift count is computed from `count & 0x3F`.

On some hardware architectures, shifting an int by 32 will yield 0, while other architectures will yield the same int. In order to have consistent behavior, the designers of C# had to choose one of those options. The current behavior simply requires performing `& 0x1F` on the shift count on architectures that otherwise yield 0. However, always returning 0 would require a comparison and a branch on architectures that yield the int. Since branches tend to be expensive, it makes sense that they chose the option that is fastest in the most cases.

Comment: And you can fix it with `0x1111L`.

Comment: @Gabe Thank You! That is it, and declaring a long as Henk said or casting to one works as expected. (big *facepalm* for me!)

Comment: (And thank you for updating with the extra information about how and why the count is masked, its always interesting to know the details behind the behaviour)

Answer (score 1):

I believe its because `0x1111` is treated as an `int`.